# Apache Commons Net API usage

Tags: java, ftp

I am making a program to connect to FTP Server using FTPCLient class of apache commons net API. here is code:

```
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    byte[] b = new byte[4];
    b[ 0] = new Integer(127).byteValue();
    b[ 1] = new Integer(0).byteValue();
    b[ 2] = new Integer(0).byteValue();
    b[ 3] = new Integer(1).byteValue();
    try{

            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(b);
        client.connect(address,22);

       }
```

.....
I get the exception at connect line().

```
org.apache.commons.net.MalformedServerReplyException: Could not parse response code.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
 FTPClient f = new FTPClient();
 f.connect(server);
 f.login(username, password);
 FTPFile[] files = listFiles(directory);
```

**Note:** port 22 is used for SSH,sftp not for ftp

If its sftp then you need to go for [commons-vfs](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/)